# C: Segmentation Fault when writing to Array Pointer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write to an element in a color array via a pointer in a function. The function is:

```
void setColor(int color1[3],int color2[3], int *red, int *green, int *blue) {
int redInc = (color2[1]-color1[1])/range;
int greenInc = (color2[2]-color1[2])/range;
int blueInc = (color2[3]-color1[3])/range;

int i = 0;
while (i < range) {
    *(red+i) = color1[1] + i*redInc;
    printf("This is red: %s\n",*(red+i));
    *(green+i) = color1[2] + i*greenInc;
    *(blue+i) = color1[3] + i*blueInc;
    i++;
}
return;}
```

Range is defined as a constant of 21. Inside of the main loop:

```
int color1[3] = {255,0,0};
int color2[3] = {0,255,0};

int red[21] = {0};
int green[21] = {0};
int blue[21] = {0};

setColor(color1,color2,red,green,blue);
```

I've tried this code on my Linux machine and it seems to work, but it Seg Faults on my Raspberry Pi. Is it how I'm trying to access the array?

Comment: `color1[3]` is out of range.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1, in almost all programming languages.

Comment: Invest some time to learn to use Macros instead of ugly digits when playing around with Arrays

Comment: Also there is a nicer syntax for `*(red + i)` - namely, `red[i]`.

Comment: Rolled back. You must not change your question once you have answers if those loose context from the edit. This is no interactive debugging site!

Comment: @olaf How do you show updated code then?

Comment: @calvinjarrod: Read [ask]! You also should have taken the [tour] during registration. After two years you should know how SO works.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy. The consensus is that other users should proactively revert such changes. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 2):

C is zero indexed, meaning if you have an array 3 ints long, you access it with indices 0, 1 and 2

example:

```
int ex[3] = {1,2,3};
printf("%d %d %d", ex[0], ex[1], ex[2]);
```

will output:

```
1 2 3
```

So, what you need to do, is go over your code and check where you are indexing arrays improperly, which looks like all of them inside the function `void setColor(int color1[3],int color2[3], int *red, int *green, int *blue)`

Comment: Okay. Can't believe I missed the off-by-one error. That's corrected. However it works on my Linux machine. Its just supposed to make a status bar with different colors for each bar increment. But when I compile it on my Raspberry Pi, it seg faults.

Comment: @calvinjarrod As mentioned in other answers, indexing past the end of the array is undefined behavior. So sometimes it will not crash your program, but that doesn't mean it's working as you intend. This might have to do with your variable `range`. I'm looking in the post and you don't provide the definition of it. You say "...In the main loop". If `range` is always the same value, I recommend `#define`ing it. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it how I'm trying to access the array?

Yes! Array indexing starts 0 and ends at size - 1, where size is the length of your array.

---

Here:

```
*(blue+i) = color1[3] + i*blueInc;
```

`color1` is out of range, since it has size of 3:

```
int color1[3] = {255,0,0};
```

and you access it past `color1[2]`, which causes *Undefined Behavior*, and most likely the segmentation fault you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

As you intialized the `array` `color1[3]`, the indexes you can use are `0`, `1`, and `2`, so you should change that values, because when you try to access the position `3` in the `array`, it gives a segmentation fault, because it is out of index. 
Hope you understand!